# problem after update 4.9.6

Tags: breadcrumb

I see the lines
Catchable fatal error: Object of class WP_Error could not be converted to string in /www/htdocs/w00d66ef/wp-content/themes/rttheme15/rt-framework/functions/rt_breadcrumb.php on line 40

what does this means ?
I´m not a specialist. I hope someone can explain this in a few simple words.

Thanks in advance.

Best regards
Uwe

Comment: It means that your theme is not compatible with new WP version. It does something wrong and doesn't handle errors properly. You should contact the author of that theme...

Answer (score 2):

This means that your theme isn't compatible with the new version of Wordpress. Here's what you can do:

- **You have to update your theme if an update is available.**
- **You can go back to the old version of Wordpress which I don't think
  you should be doing.**
- **Try updating your PHP version.**

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Updating PHP won't help, I guess - it's an WP error, not a PHP one...

Comment: This do can help sometimes honestly. :o

Comment: Yes, it can help sometimes. But this time the reason is stated clearly - theme tries to do something with some string and ignores, that it can be an WP_Error and not only string... PHP version has nothing to do with this...

Comment: Oh ok. That was just one of the options that might help.